# Переход на другое приложение

Tags: android-sdk, android, activity

Как сделать кнопку, чтобы при нажатии которой происходил переход в activity другого андроид приложения - в `net.xxx.yy/net.xxx.yy.Activity1`.

Comment: @Mgchannel, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_MAIN);        
    intent.setClassName("net.xxx.yy", "net.xxx.yy.Activity1");        
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Вполне возможно, что нужно будет подобрать правильный action (`ACTION_MAIN`, `ACTION_VIEW` и т.д.).

ЗЫ Не помешало бы в вопросе больше подробностей. Свое приложение/чужое. Какой фильтр у activity в манифесте прописан и т.д.